# How to stop rethinkdbs Next (.Changes())

Tags: go

I am currently using `RethinkDB` in my app because of their real time event driven data. I currently have this watch function that checks for users that are online:

```
func (c *connection) watchUsers() {
    db := common.DB()
    query := gorethink.Table("Users").Filter(map[string]interface{}{
        "online": 1,
    }).Changes(gorethink.ChangesOpts{
        IncludeInitial: true,
    })
    res, err := query.Run(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer res.Close()
    var users interface{}
    for res.Next(&users) {
        if c.disconnecting {
            break
        }
        usersNewMap := users.(map[string]interface{})["new_val"]
        user := usersNewMap.(map[string]interface{})
        log.Println(user["username"])
        c.ws.WriteJSON(wsMsg{
            "user add",
            map[string]interface{}{
                "username": user["username"].(string),
                "uuid":     user["id"].(string),
            },
        })
    }
    log.Println("Ended on disconnect")
}
```

The only problem is I need the `watchUsers` function to return when the websocket disconnects. Right now I have

```
defer func() {
   c.disconnecting = true
}()
```

in the websocket its self which then when the watch tries to get more data on another announcement, it then will break the loop and end the goroutine. The only problem is what if there is no data to be broadcasted for a while and now this goroutine just hangs out for a while taking up unnecessary space. So my question is, how can I break this for loop with some sort of event driven method, it would be easier if I could just have `res.Next` be a channel because then I could use a select but this is not the case.

Comment: Your code might have a race on connection.disconnecting.  Run with the race detector.  I think your best bet is to [close the underlying network connection](https://godoc.org/github.com/dancannon/gorethink#Connection.Close) to the database.  This should cause Next to return immedidatly with an error.

Comment: @CodingPickle I've been using one connection for basically everything, I don't know if that is good or bad practice. So if I .close I think every other connection would be affected No race conditions either btw from what I can see using --race

Comment: I suspected a race because I assumed that `c.disconnecting = true` is executed from a different goroutine from the goroutine than the one that executes ` if c.disconnecting {`.

Comment: @CodingPickle there actually may be but that's not my biggest concern at the moment :)

Comment: @CodingPickle Thanks for the `res.Close()` suggestion, I've posted an answer and gave you credit, I would just delete it normally after finding an answer without one being posted here yet but `Go` seems to need all the Q&A it can get from my experience x.x

Comment: The code as written handles breaking out of a loop when the condition is detected.  The issue is that Next blocks. I suggest changing the title to "how to break out of rethinkdb's Next" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution, which seems to work fine using a suggestion from @CodingPickle, in a nutshell, run the for loop in its own goroutine and then do `res.Close()` when its done watching.

```
func (c *connection) watchUsers() {
    db := common.DB()
    query := gorethink.Table("Users").Filter(map[string]interface{}{
        "online": 1,
    }).Changes(gorethink.ChangesOpts{
        IncludeInitial: true,
    })
    res, err := query.Run(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    go func(res *gorethink.Cursor, c *connection) {
        defer res.Close()
        var users interface{}
        for res.Next(&users) {
            usersNewMap := users.(map[string]interface{})["new_val"]
            user := usersNewMap.(map[string]interface{})
            c.send <- wsMsg{
                "user add",
                map[string]interface{}{
                    "username": user["username"].(string),
                    "uuid":     user["id"].(string),
                },
            }
        }
        log.Println("Ended gracefully")
    }(res, c)

    select {
    case <-c.disconnecting:
        res.Close()
        break
    case <-c.stopWatchingUsers:
        res.Close()
        break
    }
}
```